# dbx command not found in SunOS Solaris 11.2

Tags: unix, solaris, dbx

I am a newbie in Unix/Linux. There's no command found when I type dbx in the terminal.Could you please tell me how to work it out? Thanks.

My Solaris version is 11.2

Comment: I have the Solaris installed in vmware 10, and the host os is windows 8.

Comment: `dbx` is part of the Solaris Studio development set.  (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index-jsp-142272.html)  Is it installed?

Comment: @Shirley Feng - check if is installed using the command `whereis dbx`

Comment: @sras - whereis cannot be found either:(

Comment: @AndrewHenle thank you! I've installed the solaris studio dev set according to the website you posted. And now the problem is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not know and you do not know I am assuming the default install path:

```
ls /opt/sun/*
```

If this command returns an error or shows no files, then you do not have sun studio, and therefore you do not have dbx.

If the above command works, let's now find the command:
To locate dbx (it should be in `/opt/sun/sunstudio11/bin` but may be elsewhere )

try:

```
find /opt/sun -name dbx
```

Let's pretend it returns `/opt/sun/sunstudio11/bin/dbx`  This means that

`/opt/sun/sunstudio11/bin/` is the directory dbx lives in.  Add it to your PATH variable:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/opt/sun/sunstudio11/bin/
export PATH
```

Now the shell will run dbx when you simply type `dbx`

If you want it to be permenanent, then edit (in your home directory )
your `.profile`  ( or `.bash_profile` for bash) file with the two lines above.